# Проблема с autoload: не удается подключиться

Tags: php, codeigniter

Хочу прописать в `application/congig/autoload.php $autoload('libraries') = array('database')`. После этого выдаёт ошибку в браузер типа

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: Z:\home\testci.com\www\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124

Искал ответ на форуме, что-то ничего не получилось. Может, в настройках что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Именно, вам необходимо в настройках CodeIgniter прописать данные для соединения с базой данных. Он же об этом вам и говорит. Файл **database.php**

Вам нужно указать:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';//айпи/хост сервера
$db['default']['username'] = 'логин';//логин для доступа к БД
$db['default']['password'] = 'пароль';//пароль
$db['default']['database'] = 'имя базы данных';//имя вашей БД
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';//тип БД, которую вы используете
```

Comment: а где там в application/config/database.php прописывать? если можно, напишите поконкретнее пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

в application/config/database.php прописывать или заменять на ваши настройки

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //тут название хоста
$db['default']['username'] = 'username'; //здесь имя пользователя базы
$db['default']['password'] = 'password'; //тут пароль к базе
$db['default']['database'] = 'name_base'; // здесь имя базы
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'cp1251'; // если в этой кодировке сайт
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'cp1251_general_ci'; // если в этой кодировке база(они должны совпадать)
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

это для версии CI 2.0.3

Comment: спасибо большое, оказывается я просто логин неправильный указал, вот что делает невнимательность)))